# How do I move a Question back from MSE to MSO

Tags: support, mso-mse-split, tags, migration

I had a question about merging tags on MSO, that is not yet resolved, and which got moved from MSO to MSE in the big re-org of 2014-04.

Since the question is about SO tags, I assume that it really does belong on MSE and would like to move it back there.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226451/merge-tags-google-search-api-google-custom-search-and-google-cse

Will this happen automatically in some post-re-org clean-up?  Should I flag it for moderator attention?

(I guess this question itself might belong on MSE, but I believe we are instructed to ask here if uncertain.)

Comment: How do I move a Question back from MSE to MSO - I think so only moderators of MSE can do that

Comment: I don't think the migration of existing questions from MSE to MSO has completed yet.

Comment: @TGMCians - well none of my questions/answers have been migrated yet and I can't believe that they're *all* network related.

Comment: @TGMCians They've started migrating questions, they haven't finished.

Comment: @Kevin Yeah Right

Comment: @TGMCians It *can* be done, but Tim (and his colleagues?) are currently working on migrating some stuff in batches. At the moment [we're being asked not to flag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229785/should-we-flag-questions-on-mse-that-are-strictly-about-so/229787#229787). After that, I don't know.

Comment: @Gilles Alright !

Comment: Closely related: [Will the questions be migrated over from meta. stackexchange.com?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250001)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Flag it. Explain why it should be moved. For example:

- "This post is relevant to an ongoing issue specific to Stack Overflow and I'd like to work on it."
- "I'm referencing this in a post on Meta Stack Overflow, and since it has no outstanding links from Meta Stack Exchange, I think it would be better off moved."
- "I'm trying to woo a programmer by demonstrating my involvement in the Stack Overflow community, but my awesome, Stack Overflow-specific answer was moved to Meta Stack Exchange - don't hang me out to dry, bro!"

[Just don't flag everything.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229785/should-we-flag-questions-on-mse-that-are-strictly-about-so/229787#229787)

Comment: Aren't these posts going to be automagically migrated soon anyway?

Comment: Not all of them.

Comment: Right, but ones which can be determined to be relevant by an algorithm.

Comment: I don't trust algorithms. They'll be determined by Tim's careful review, flags from MSO users, and my capricious whims.

Comment: Are the posts moved in their entirety or simply copied? Will these migration flags also be possible to be reviewed/accepted in the future once the split is more mature?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, @Travis.

Comment: Sorry, I will try to be clearer. I was curious if the posts that are moved from MSE back to MSO would exist in both places once moved. And also I was curious if the facility to move the posts from MSE to MSO would still be allowed in the future (as opposed to only being available during the current review by yourself, Tim, or team members).

Comment: There's no plan to ever completely *disallow* this, @Travis. We'll move large numbers (more than 1 or 2 at a time) using a tool that doesn't bump them and does delete the original - but individual migrations will remain possible, and behave in the usual manner.

Comment: For the record, I flagged it as suggested and soon afterwards it got moved (i.e. likely as a result of the flogging).